# Promise with map and reduce returns a TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, promise, reduce

I have a `JSON` object that contains array of objects, inside each of them there is `key:value` object with 2 entries and each entry has it's own fields.

```
[
  {
    "application": {
      "some key": "some value 1",
      "another key": "another value 1"
    },
    "data": [
      {
        "some key": "value",
        "another key": "value"
      },
      {
        "some key": "value",
        "another key": "value"
      },
      {
        "some key": "value",
        "another key": "value"
      },
      {
        "some key": "value",
        "another key": "value"
      }
    ]
  },
    {
    "application": {
      "some key": "some value 2",
      "another key": "another value 2"
    },
    "data": [
      {
        "some key": "value",
        "another key": "value"
      },
      {
        "some key": "value",
        "another key": "value"
      },
      {
        "some key": "value",
        "another key": "value"
      },
      {
        "some key": "value",
        "another key": "value"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm trying to (1) `map` the array and then (2) use `reduce` in order to extract some values that I need from that `key:value` objects.

```
  const createGroupedData = (data) => {
    const promises = data.reduce(async (acc, obj) => {
      const month = moment.unix(obj.userComment.lastModified.seconds).format('MMMM');
      const rating = obj.userComment.starRating.toString();

      if (!acc[month]) {
        acc[month] = {};
      }

      if (!acc[month][rating]) {
        acc[month][rating] = [];
      }

      acc[month][rating].push(obj);
      return acc;
    }, {});

    return Promise.all(promises);
  }

  const createGroupedObject = async (reviewObjects) => {
    const appPromises = reviewObjects.map(async (reviewObject, index) => {
      return {
        application: reviewObject.application,
        data: await createGroupedData(reviewObject.data)
      };
    });

    return Promise.all(appPromises);
  };

// Do the magic!
createGroupedObject(data);
```

I am getting an error of:

`TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))`

From this row:

[image]

Anyone know why?

Comment: Besides the `async` statement, how is the code of the `createGroupedData` asynchronous?

Comment: Please, enlighten me, because I want to understand and learn what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Hard to say without the data

Comment: You can check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75512130/1138498

Comment: The TypeError is caused by `promises` not being an array after `data.reduce(...)`

Comment: your reducer is returning an object since you gave it an initial value `{}`  and not array of promises as Promises.all() expects

Comment: @Joschi I've added a link to the JSON data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understand the purpose of `createGroupedData` is supposed to go over the data array and group related values in the array to a Map. essentially all values belonging to the same key will be will be put in an array as values for that key.What i don't understand is why your reduce function is asynchronous given the data is passed to the function when its already resolved.

```
const createGroupedData = (data) => {
//remove async key word since there is no where 
//in the body where the reducer is waiting on some promise to resolve

const promises = data.reduce( (acc, obj) => {
  const month = moment.unix(obj.userComment.lastModified.seconds).format('MMMM');
  const rating = obj.userComment.starRating.toString();

  if (!acc[month]) {
    acc[month] = {};
  }

  if (!acc[month][rating]) {
    acc[month][rating] = [];
  }

  acc[month][rating].push(obj);
  return acc;
//use new Map() to create a Map instead of relying on an object as a Map
}, new Map());

return promises;
 }

const createGroupedObject = async (reviewObjects) => {
const appPromises = reviewObjects.map(async (reviewObject, index) => {
  return {
    application: reviewObject.application,
    //remove await createGroupedData is not asynchronous
    data:  createGroupedData(reviewObject.data)
  };
});
//this call will fail to for the same reason
return Promise.all(appPromises);
};
```

essentially noting from what you are trying to accomplish requires any promises .This might be obvious but only use them in situations where your function needs to wait for some call to complete .In this case you already have the data and all you doing is grouping it .There are no network calls or functions that need to complete in between these steps therefore no need for promises . As for the error .That is caused because Promises.all() expects and array input and you are giving it an object

Comment: using new Map() as the initial value to your reducer will cause your code to work as Map is an iterable  but essentially its not need the you return a promise in the first place